# Asymptotics of reccurence relation

Tags: complexity-theory, asymptotics, recurrence-relation

I need to tell whether $\quad\exists a \quad T(n) = \omega(n^2)$

$T(n) = T(\frac{n}{2}) + aT(\frac{n}{4}) + n^2\\\\
\forall n<10 \quad T(n) = 1$
And if there is such $a$ I need to find the minimum one.

I have tried to use recurrence tree but im unable to generalize $T(n)$ to a finite sum and im quite out of ideas on how to attack this problem.

Comment: I don't see any complexity here. You are interested in the asymptotic rate of growth of $T(n)$. The function $T(n)$ could be counting primes, in which case its asymptotics are still interesting although there is no complexity involved.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Akra–Bazzi method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method)?

Comment: Also, note that a *minimal* $a$ need not exist; but the infimum over all good $a$ does always exist.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Edited the post to better suit the question, thank you.
I'm not familiar with the method, I'll look into it altough it is not something I learned in class so probably i won't be able to use it in hw.

Comment: Although this site is mostly used to help people with their homework, to answer this question, the correct tool is the Akra–Bazzi theorem, and I don't see any reason to restrict myself to whatever is allowed in your class. In real life math we can use whatever is known, not whatever some professor decided arbitrarily is allowed.

Comment: Furthermore, the Akra–Bazzi theorem, in a sense, described what would happen if you carefully use the recurrence tree method. Having used it, there is no need to reprove the result using a recurrence tree.

Comment: I looked into this theorem.
One of the conditions is : $a_i >0 \forall i$, 
But dosen't that mean im restricting myself to find $inf\{ a\}$ which is non- negative?

Comment: I am afraid so. This is in line with what happens when you form a recurrence tree – can you have a negative number of children?

Comment: Another implicit assumption might be that $a$ is an integer. This is definitely not needed for Akra–Bazzi, but if your recurrence represents the time complexity of some function, that $a$ would be integral.

Comment: It is not mentioned but It 'feels' like $p$ must be an integer (?) , is it true? or $p$ can be any real number?

Comment: Not at all. The parameter $p$ need not be an integer.